# SQL Stored Procedures within Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2013

I feel as though i may be beating a dead horse but i'll post this in case i have missed something.

I'm currently converting a .adp to .accdb as we're moving to access 2013, everything has been easy to recreate with the exception of the stored procedures and scalar functions.

I've done a bit of reading around and it looks as though i will have to code this within VBA (which is all well and good). I'm just checking in to see if i've possibly missed something within Access 2013 that will allow me to create a stored function similar to access 2007.

Comment: To clarify, you're changing an ADP that used SQL Server as a backing store to an ACCDB where Access is both the frontend UI *and* also the backing store?

Comment: ^This. The usual way would be to keep the tables (and views) on SQL Server and link them from Access. And keep the Stored Procedures there too (and run them e.g. with a Pass-Through query in Access).

Comment: I guess that's where my issue lies, when looking at the old .adp (one that i didn't create) i noted that the stored function my predecessor was calling was completely written (comments and all) rather than just calling the function within sql.